# Better alternative of the for loop on a 10 million big dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have written a code that works fine. It looks like below: I need to optimize the runtime.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        if df['event_name'][i] in ['add_basket_click','remove_basket_click'] and df['event_name'][i-1]=='product_search':
            try:
                if df['event_desc'][i]['firebase_screen_id']==df['event_desc'][i-1]['firebase_screen_id']:
                    df.at[i,'search_process']=1
            except:
                pass
    except:
        pass
```

Below is a sample dataset:

```
user_id event_name  event_desc
10  product_search  {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}
10  add_basket_click    {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}
10  start   {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}
10  add_basket_click    {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}
```

Output:

```
user_id event_name  event_desc  search_process
10  product_search  {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'} 0
10  add_basket_click    {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'} 1
10  start   {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'} 0
10  add_basket_click    {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'} 0
```

Comment: Data sample should be great :)

Comment: thank you,but not easy verify solutions, is possible create some 10 rows with  expected output?

Comment: @jezrael, added a simple dataset.

Comment: I try run your sample data and no new column, also if add `df['search_process']=0` there is no change `1` for second row.

Comment: you can add a new column as df['search_process']=0 and then try

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need test `firebase_previous_id` instead `firebase_screen_id` in dictionary in column `event_desc`:

```
m1 = df['event_name'].shift() =='product_search'
m2 = df['event_name'].isin(['add_basket_click','remove_basket_click'])
#changed values for non matched values after get
s1 = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: x.get('firebase_previous_id', 'not_m'))
s2 = df['event_desc'].apply(lambda x: x.get('firebase_previous_id', 'not_matched'))
m3 = s1 == s2.shift()

df['search_process'] = (m1 & m2 & m3).astype(int)
print (df)
   user_id        event_name                                       event_desc  \
0       10    product_search  {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}   
1       10  add_basket_click  {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}   
2       10             start  {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}   
3       10  add_basket_click  {'firebase_previous_id': '8996730796507124997'}   

   search_process  
0               0  
1               1  
2               0  
3               0
```

Answer (score 2):

try splitting the data processing over multiple `Processes` (ideally matching the number of cores that your PC has) using the `multiprocessing` package.